# Creating a two toned symmetric pattern overlay on top of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Does anyone know how to create this black and white pattern overlay effect in photoshop? I've tried the film grain filter and the half tone pattern filter and I haven't been able to create the sharpness or clarity of the pattern in this image.

p.s you might need to zoom in on the to see it.
[image: tour de france image]

Answer (score 4):

1 - Create a new image with 2x2px, three pixels white, with one pixel black.

[image]

2 - Make it a Pattern with Edit > Define Pattern

3 - Open your picture.

4 - Create a new layer over the picture, and fill it with the pattern created.

5 - Blend the pattern with layer property "screen"

[image]

You can make bigger patterns (ie: 10x10px) if you wish to increase pixel visibility. And it works with different patterns and colored images too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image must be high-resolution to start with, so that you can get the dots proportionately small but still have a bit of room to manipulate them with the missing step: Smart Sharpen.

First copy the layer; work only on the copy.

The dots produced by the Haltone Pattern are anti-aliased, so they're not sharp. Increasing the contrast slider in the filter doesn't help, because it increases the *overall image contrast*. Set it to 0.

What you want to do is increase the contrast at the edges of the dots, so after you've created your halftone pattern, apply Smart Sharpen with a radius of about the size of your dots, or a little larger. Zoom in to about 400% in the preview so you can see what you're doing. What you're trying to achieve is the blackest dot you can.

Try placing a very light gray layer beneath your halftone layer, set a Blend Mode of Darken or Multiply on the halftone and experiment from there. Reduce the overall opacity until you have the effect you want.